# How to make xcalib always start up automatically?

Tags: 11.10, startup

I added the command `xcalib -gc 1.2 monitor-profile.icc` to my startup applications.

It does set up the monitor colors in regard to a calibration file (icc). It works, however after about 1 or 2 seconds it gets overwritten by standard settings again. I think Ubuntu runs some monitor calibration by itself. Can you help me out?

I am on 11.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, a simple solution would be to first let the system write the settings and then overwrite them yourself ;)

So, you should add to your command a timeout at first, so as to let the system do what it has to do, and then you should overwrite these settings. This should be your command:

```
bash -c 'sleep 10 && xcalib -gc 1.2 monitor-profile.icc'
```

This will wait 10 seconds at first (you may need to tweak this timeout so as to much your needs) and then it will execute your command.

As a result, you will overwrite what the system has written and not vice versa.

Comment: The `bash -c 'sleep 10s &&` proved to be indispensable for use with XFCE Application Autostart in Xubuntu LTS. Thanks!