# How do you set system display color profiles in Xubuntu and Lubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, lubuntu, ubuntu-studio, color-management

Some applications, such as Gimp, Geeqie and Rawstudio claim to be able to use system color profile in their color management, but how do you setup such a profile? How do you see, if such a profile has been set, and if it has been set, how do you see which profile is used? I don't see how to do it in Lubuntu and Xubuntu.

Comment: You can now use `xiccd` to avoid the need for any Gnome/KDE/Unity dependencies when using `colord`;  http://askubuntu.com/q/427821/25639 explains how to install it.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 https://askubuntu.com/a/1464815/289138 - a success(?) story, still needs evaluation at this writing though.

Answer (score 20):

This is a good question, as Xubuntu and Lubuntu don't have the same system settings > color menu that the standard Ubuntu has, and installing `gnome-color-manager` does not allow you to set the profiles in a Xubuntu or Xfce session, as you you can only use that utility properly when running a gnome session, as it depends on `gnome-settings-daemon` and `gnome-control-center`. This fact is clear from the useful diagram [presented here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/colord/specifics.html) in this article.

**System Tools**

However, on Xubuntu and Lubuntu, the `colord` package is still automatically installed and takes care of color management, and you can access it on the command-line using `colormgr`. You can query your devices such as printers and scanners by using command-line switches  such as `colormgr get-devices`, which are delineated [at the official site](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/colord/using.html).

However, while `colormgr get-devices` will list all the automatically color-managed devices on your system, it will **not** list display devices on `xfce`.

On `xfce`, `colormgr get-devices-by-kind display` will not work and you will not be able to set the icc profile for the display on the command-line, but only by using tools such as `xicc` or `xcalib` (see further below). This is explained [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47189) by Richard Hughes:

> XFCE has no session component for colord. You need to either run gnome-settings-daemon (which has a color plugin), kded with colord-kde installed, or write something lightweight for XFCE.
>
> Colord only detects system devices like scanners and webcams, and then CUPS registers printers. It has no access to the session, and relies on a session component to talk to X and register devices.

---

In a `gnome` or `kde` session (which you could be running on Xubuntu) you should be able to use `colormgr` to enter `colormgr get-devices-by-kind display` and set the icc profile for the display manually, so for completeness I present this method.

You first have to add your profiles to `~/.local/share/icc` and run `colormgr get-profiles` to list them, and then choose the icc profile, such as

```
/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/icc_86894053ff74b24d0c304fc3bd0e9c76
```

Now add it to the desired device (this time it is the default display) with

```
colormgr device-add-profile /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_default /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/icc_86894053ff74b24d0c304fc3bd0e9c76
```

Then you can make it default with

```
colormgr device-make-profile-default /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_default /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/icc_86894053ff74b24d0c304fc3bd0e9c76
```

---

**Other useful Utilities**

Note: Custom icc profiles should go in `/home/$USER/.local/share/icc`; the system directory is `/usr/share/color/icc`.

It is possible to use tools such as `xicc` or `xcalib` if you want to setup a specific icc profile on Xubuntu or Lubuntu. All you need do is point either of these tools at your icc profile and place that command in startup:

```
xicc /location/of/profile
```

or with `xcalib` you can specify gamma correction as well using

```
xcalib -gc 1.8 /location/of/profile
```

However, as the question below shows, you may need to delay the execution of the command so the system does not override your choice:

- [How to make xcalib always start up automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175628/how-to-make-xcalib-always-start-up-automatically)

Alternatively, you may want to use `xicc`, as the profiles set with that application are designed to be picked up by certain applications such as `Gimp`- this is exactly what you refer to in your question, and this program is probably what you were thinking of. To load a profile, just run `xicc /location/of/profile`; you can specify the display if necessary.

The package notes for `xicc`explain that

> This utility lets you set an ICC colour profile for an X display, so that
>    applications can use it to display colour calibrated images.  Applications have
>    to specifically look for this atom but several applications such as Gimp and
>    Krita already do.

Alternatively, you can usually set profiles explicitly in applications such as the Gimp (see screenshot below) and other programs. This may be necessary if you are working with RAW images that may demand a specific colorspace.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for diverse answer. As for xicc, I wonder what kind of "atom" do they mean. Is it just the system monitor profile option that is displayed in the screenshot?

Comment: I get no output for `colormgr get-devices-by-kind display`. I guess that indicates that system display profile is undefined.

Comment: @jarno see my edit re `colormgr` on xfce systems.

Comment: It seems to me that xcalib and xicc are not alternatives to each other, but they complement each other: xcalib sets X server gamma ramp according to data that may be included in the provided ICC profile, and that setting has effect regardless of applications, whereas xicc sets system display profile that may or may not be applied by applications.

Comment: It might be difficult to apply different settings for different monitors, if you use extended desktop: In my setup xcalib changed settings for the integrated monitor of my notebook only and I did not find a way to set calibration for an external monitor, when extended desktop is in use. I didn't test xicc in this respect, but I guess it is the same.

Comment: @jarno That's an interesting point, and it would make a good, separate question to ask, as you did not specify this factor in the original question.

Comment: jarno, see http://www.darktable.org/2013/05/display-color-management-in-darktable/ So there are two parts to a profile, the vcgt (whole-screen gamma+whitepoint) and "the rest" (which individual applications use, and is set in the _ICC_PROFILE atom – check if set with `xprop -display :0.0 -len 14 -root _ICC_PROFILE`)

Comment: Be careful about `colormgr`. I tried tools mentioned here on Xubuntu 13.10. After I played with `colormgr device-add-profile /path/to/device /path/to/randomprofile` not only could I not see any change, but I got `gnome-settings-daemon` permanently broken for all users on the machine. Launching it would crash immediately with `color-plugin:ERROR:gsd-color-manager.c:905:gcm_session_device_assign_profile_connect_cb: assertion failed: (filename != NULL)` .

Comment: I could fix the permanently broken `gnome-settings-daemon` problem by killing `colord` and moving away `/var/lib/colord/mapping.db`. That file is a SQLite3 database where `colormgr` has `colord` record device-to-profile associations. Hope this may help similar cases.

Comment: so can I start a Gnome session, calibrate, save the calibration, and then have it load and work in a xfce (or other) session?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, there is an excellent german howto all necessary things manually: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Monitor_profilieren_mit_ArgyllCMS

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to work through this on Lubuntu 17.04 so this is how it worked for me. My Lubuntu system is on an old Dell laptop primarily used for emails and internet browsing with Firefox.

The first priority was to get Firefox colour managed. Fortunately it can be done in the application alone. Navigate a Firefox browser window to

> about:config

and after the warning page search for

> color_man

this will list the colour management properties for Firefox. Set display_profile to the location of your icc profile. It should be located in your ~/.local/share/icc/ directory ie

> /home/user/.local/share/icc/my_screen_profile.icc

If no profile is set here Firefox will try to use the system profile, but we've got none set yet. Se enablev4 to

> true

to allow v4 profiles. Set mode to

> 1

where 0 = disable colour management, 1 = enable for all rendered graphics, 2 = enable for profile tagged images only. Set rendering_intent to

> 0

where  0 = perceptual, 1 relative colormetric, 2 = saturation,3 = absolute colormetric. Restart Firefox and you are done. Test your browser by going to [color.org](http://www.color.org/version4html.xalter). There is one problem here though. Whilst the browser is colour managed, the pdf preview isn't. You can check this out with the pdf version. If you send the file to the default pdf viewer Evince Document Viewer 3.24.0 it is rendered correctly though.

Firefox settings taken from [NTown Productions](http://ntown.at/2013/12/28/firefox-color-management/)

Although this is probably adequate for what I need, this wasn't he solution I was after so further research and a slow Sunday led me to the following which sets up colour management for the system.

Login in to synaptic and install

> colord

and

> xiccd

If I was doing this first, without having set up Firefox I can open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and use colormgr to import my display profile from any location into ~/.local/share/icc/ like this

> colormgr import-profile /home/user/Downloads/my_screen_profile.icc

Be careful with filenames. I had problems with white space in the filenames I created making the profiles with Argyll / DisplayCAL. It seemed best to keep the filenames short and simple. For some reason I have to run this command more than once. The first run copied the file into my icc directory, the second run actually imports the file into the colord system and reports back with a summary of the profile including meta and the profiles "object path". Next we can check that xiccd has allowed colord to interact with the display with the command

> colormgr get-devices-by-kind display

This returns a summary which includes the display device's "object path" required for adding the profile with the command

> colormgr device-add-profile "display device object path" "profile object path"

The object paths are long so I used shift+ctrl+c to copy and shift+ctrl+v to paste in my terminal window. If you run

> colormgr get-devices-by-kind display

again you should see your profile in position 1) making it the default profile. If it isn't or you want to change the default use

> colormgr device-make-profile-default "display device object path" "profile object path"

and removed with

> colormgr delete-profile "display device object path" "profile object path"

Other options can be found from

> colormgr --help

To test this I used this method [rawpedia](http://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/How_to_extract_and_examine_ICC_profiles) and the extracticc command from the [argyll](https://www.argyllcms.com/) package on the jpg with the mixed up sRGB profile on the [color.org](http://www.color.org/version4html.xalter) page, then added this to my display in the same way as above. I then blanked out the display_profile setting in Firefox prompting it to use the system profile on restart. The browser now displayed sGBR ie red for green and vice versa.
Other references in addition to the answer above by user76204

[ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ICC_profiles)

[pcode](https://encrypted.pcode.nl/blog/2013/11/24/display-color-profiling-on-linux/)

All offer similar advice but did not quite work on my system.

Note. The default image viewer in Lubuntu 17.04 is GPicView which is not colour managed, so use synaptic to swap it for eog or eye of gnome image viewer.