# How use "Color" and ICC profiles to calibrate screen?

Tags: screen, acer, aspire

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in an Aspire 5250-BZ699, and I would like to calibrate the screen - but I don't' know how to use "Color" and how to apply the ICC profiles. Is there a tutorial to do this?

Comment: For alternatives to `color` like `xicc` or `xcalib`, see my answer [for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/199661/how-do-you-set-system-display-color-profiles-in-xubuntu-and-lubuntu/236516#236516).