# How to use GNOME Color Manager in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, color-management

I need to correct colours displayed by my monitor. From the 'Ubuntu Software Center' I have installed the 'GNOME Color Manager', but I cannot use it for making my own colour profile: I have not found it (as usually with a new software) in the dash window to be able to run it (and possibly lock to the launcher) and see how to edit a colour profile by it.
From the page recommended, I have downloaded the file gnome-color-manager_3.4.0-1_i386.deb and double-clicked at its row in Krusader. Something installed for about 1 second (after previous sudo commands the system does not require the password), but I do not yet see how to run the program installed. Terminal commands that I guessed do not work: I tried e.g

```
tatatom@Katedrala:~$ gnome-color-manager 
gnome-color-manager: command not found 
tatatom@Katedrala:~$ gnome-color-manager_3.4.0 
gnome-color-manager_3.4.0: command not found
tatatom@Katedrala:~$ color
color: command not found
tatatom@Katedrala:~$ argyll
argyll: command not found
```

, though

```
tatatom@Katedrala:~$ krusader
```

works OK and the 'Ubuntu Software Center' shows that I do have the 'Color' 'GNOME Color Manager' installed, with a 'Color Management System, calibrator and profiler (argyll)' Add-on, and offers their removing.

Answer (score 2):

The naming is indeed counterintuitive.
As per the [colormanage documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-color-manager/2.32/using.html.en) it can be either launched from the GNOME Preferences Menu or by invoking:

```
$ gcm-prefs --verbose
```

on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

I guess gnome-color-manager is not working because you don't use the unity (or gnome?) desktop. The answer in [How do you set system display color profiles in Xubuntu and Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199661/how-do-you-set-system-display-color-profiles-in-xubuntu-and-lubuntu) has some details...

Answer (score 0):

The below is for calibrating my scanner.  For a monitor you'll need a device like the datacolor3 or datacolor4 to read the display and make a profile.  For a scanner, you need a target and data file.  For a printer, you need to print the target and read the print to make a profile.

I'm attempting to work through the process in my Ubuntu 12.04. I started by opening up the "Color" icon in Dash. There is some needed auto installs when initially selecting my Epson scanner and hitting calibrate. After the installs, hit calibrate again and the Gnome Color Manager opens. There is a pop-up to install shared-color-targets that fails. This sent me off to find a debian package, but only found an RPM. I used Alien to make it a deb and dpkg -i package.deb. The location of install is /usr/share/color and /usr/share/shared-color-targets. This far, I've just setup the framework for the Gnome Color Manager to function properly, but no color targets are present, and these must be purchased from www.targets.coloraid.de/. You only need one target to calibrate your whole system as it is the anchor by which everything will be made to match it later.

Answer (score -1):

Gnome color manager could be found on ubuntuupdates.org site. [Here is the package for 12.04.](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/base/gnome-color-manager)

Comment: Though I edited the answer I still not sure how it answers the question. Shouldn't you provide more details?

Comment: From the page, I have downloaded the file gnome-color-manager_3.4.0-1-i386 and double-clicked at its row in Krusader. Something installed for about 1 second (after previous sudo commands the system does not require the password), but I do not yet see how to run the program installed. Terminal commands that I guessed do not work: I tried e.g <pre>tatatom@Katedrala:~$ gnome-color-manager
gnome-color-manager: command not found
tatatom@Katedrala:~$ gnome-color-manager_3.4.0
gnome-color-manager_3.4.0: command not found
tatatom@Katedrala:~$ gnome-color-manager_3.4.0
</pre>

Comment: I am trying to edit the original question to achieve a better formatting