# How do I calibrate colors without extra hardware, like dccw.exe on Windows?

Tags: display, colors, color-management

Colors on my  monitor are too yellow.

On Windows 7, there is the color calibration tool accessible from the Control Panel, or as dccw.exe.

I'd like to calibrate color *without* extra spectrometers are other  special hardware. Note that dccw does this by showing you a series of photos and asking you to adjust colors so that the photos match a certain description (e.g., so that the difference between two shades of black is just barely visible, or that some stripes appear distinct).

How can I do that in Ubuntu?

Using Asus laptop, Xubuntu 13.10

Comment: Export the profile on Windows, convert to Ubuntu format, import there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [gnome-color-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gnome-color-manager/) to do the same in Ubuntu. For Xubuntu have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199661/how-do-you-set-system-display-color-profiles-in-xubuntu-and-lubuntu)

Comment: Thank you.  But don't you need extra hardware (measuring instrument) to do this? I'm looking for a utility that will let me calibrate colors by looking at specific photographs and adjusting colors to make the photos look a certain way, as the Windows tool does.

Comment: You can use color tool which is in `System Settings` -> `Color`. It may need to download addition packages for calibration like ICC Profile Installer, Color Picker etc..