# Why displaying colors is different between Ubuntu and windows?

Tags: windows, display, colors

I am a web developer and I do not know why colors are seen differently in Linux and windows. this is so important to designers. and how can I make displaying color colors like windows?

Comment: Please provide examples of these differences. We do NOT know about Windows, nor are we suppose to know as this is askUbuntu so we can only know about 1/2 of this question: the Ubuntu side so without examples we are not likely to be able to help.

Comment: In addition - are you dual booting the same system? Different monitors may render colors differently.

Comment: yes, I am dual booting a system and see colors are different in each one. for example #2c73ff is bluer in windows but in ubuntu it's Inclined to purple

Comment: Are you using night mode in Ubuntu and not in Windows? Are you using the same color profile in both?

Comment: I am sure the night mode is off and I did not change any display setting in both of them. I want Ubuntu to show colors like windows and i don't know how to copy color profile from windows and set it on ubuntu

Comment: Does your system have a graphics card? Is Ubuntu using that card, or is it using onboard graphics?

Comment: both are using Intel onboard graphics I think. sure about the ubuntu

Comment: Might be a dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/9443/how-to-calibrate-the-monitor-on-an-ubuntu-system or https://askubuntu.com/questions/424732/how-do-i-calibrate-colors-without-extra-hardware-like-dccw-exe-on-windows.