# Import .icm color profile from Windows

Tags: colors

Total noob in Ubuntu here so I need help for installing and using color profiles...

I have a Color profile made with a spyder3 elite hardware calibrator and saved an .icm profile in Windows 7.  I have put the .icm file on a USB stick and copied it to the Ubuntu desktop.

Till now I have tried:

- to right click it and "open with ICC profile installer" but have a "permission denied..." message,
- copy it with root access (in terminal $ sudo nautilus) to usr/share/color/icc/colord and import from there and without success.
- In system settings under color I have profile "Dell U2412M" which is my monitor but under add profile have only a few options without possibility to add my own profile...

*What is the proper way to install and use an ICM profile in Ubuntu?*

Comment: For command line solution see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/199661/how-do-you-set-system-display-color-profiles-in-xubuntu-and-lubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### To update existing Color profiles

1. Insert the USB stick (hopefully FAT32)
2. In the top right corner of the screen, click the "gears" icon
3. Choose the 3rd menu item: "system settings"
4. Click "Device Colour profiles" (looks like a colourful flower)
5. Click "add profile"
6. Choose "other profile"
7. Change in the lower right corner "Supported ICC profiles" to "All files" (icm = International Colour Microsoft)
8. Choose the USB stick from "devices" and navigate to the file and click "import"
9. *Done*

---

### To have more advanced color management

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-color-manager
```

This will install the full gnome color manager that will allow you to add your own hardware calibration, ...

Comment: Unnecessary comments deleted and above solution helped! Again, thank You wery much!!! :)

Comment: You'we welcome!  ;-)