# What is the process of installing and using a downloaded ICC Profile for my monitor?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

TFT Central, a site that reviews hardware and software has downloadable monitor/display ICC profiles.

What is the process of installing and using a downloaded ICC Profile for 
my monitor?

I am using 12.04lts 64-bit.

Comment: have you like even looked at ubuntu.com?

Comment: On the http://ubuntu.com/ it's the first version you'll be offered.

Comment: Download at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/

Answer (score 1):

for 64-bit PC (AMD64)

```
http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

for 64-bit MAC (AMD64)

```
http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to use custom ICC profiles.

For this purpose you have to install a few packages to set up custom downloaded ICC profiles. Execute following command in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-color-manager xicc xcalib
```

Then use `xicc` or `xcalib` to use custom ICC profile:

```
xicc /location/of/profile
```

or with `xcalib` you can specify gamma correction as well using

```
xcalib -gc 1.8 /location/of/profile
```

If you want to use these ICC profiles on system start, then see [How to make xcalib always start up automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175628/how-to-make-xcalib-always-start-up-automatically)